# Php Insert into adding blank entries

Tags: php, sql, insert

I'm trying to add new entries to an sql database using php,
i can add a new entry, but it adds 2 blank lines to the database.
The query i use is

```
$query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Products (Name,Id,Price) VALUES    ('$NewName','$NewId','$Price')";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn3, $query);
```

any ideas why it'd do that?

Comment: Rhys, The insert query  is correct. You need to check the other code. Or Kindly provide all the code so we can help you out further..

Comment: What do you mean by *blank lines*, empty rows in the `Products` table? If that is the case, something is triggering your query thrice. There is nothing wrong with the query itself.

Comment: Please share script before this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `VALUE` instead of `VALUES` to make sure only a single entry is added.

This should limit the insertion to a single item only. It then depends if you are keen to debug the issue more thoroughly to see what was the problem.

Lastly, it never hurts to check if the variables are all properly escaped.

Comment: Its weird, when i used VALUE it didn't do anything, when i put it back in, it added only one extra line :s

Comment: it turns out, it inserts one, but when i try to add anymore it just makes blank entries :s

Comment: ok.. and what happens if you output the query as test string and then execute the same via your server's console?

Comment: How do you do that? Sorry i've literally never used php before this week :/

Comment: Just "echo" the query and see the string - then go to your SQL database admin (e.g. phpMyAdmin) and run the query.. and see what happens.

Comment: it echos as INSERT INTO dbo.Products (Name,Id,Price) VALUE('','','')
 now :s

Comment: so you probably have a problem somewhere preceding the SQL statement.

Comment: Yeah i figured it out. :) i was sending an empty variable whenthe page loads . Nowi just gotta find out why my update page messes the rest up :P But thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.Products (Name,Id,Price) VALUES('%s','%d','%f')";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn3, sprintf($sql,mysql_real_escape_string($NewName),$NewId,$Price));
```